# What is System.out?

Tags: java, system, outputstream

I have read that `System.out` is the default output stream of Java. But what is this `out`? `System` is a class in `java.lang`, but is `out` a subclass of `System` or a variable or something else?

Comment: In the future, you can always use [grepcode](http://grepcode.com) to find out the answers to such questions: [source of System class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java)

Comment: @ppeterka Except if he happens to wonder how `String` works---they've overhauled it in the middle of the Java 7 Update stream :)

Comment: @Marko Well, even then, the OP would at least ask a question one level higher than this one was I think.

Comment: @ppeterka No, my point is, give him [this link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/). (just kidding, grepcode is much friendlier, and works 95% of time :)

Comment: @Marko the higher the wall, the more you learn from climbing it - that is true ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [System](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java) source code from the OpenJDK.

```
public final static PrintStream out = ...
```

Answer (score 4):

`out` is a **public static** `PrintStream` field in `System` class. That's why you can access it with dot operator (.) => `System.out`

Answer (score 2):

`out` is a public static field of type `PrintStream` in the `System` class.

Answer (score 2):

[`out` is a `public static final` variable of type `PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out).